# Why httpGet() causes a com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.BubbleFuelError: null?

Tags: android, rest, kotlin

I have a rest call realized by [fuel library](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel) in my Android app Kotlin project. While attempting to call httpGet I get this:

> Caused by: com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.BubbleFuelError: null
>   com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelError$Companion.wrap(FuelError.kt:84)
>   03-06 11:32:39.112 6328-6328/com.example.demo I/System.out:
>     com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.RequestTask.executeRequest(RequestTask.kt:24)
>   com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.RequestTask.call(RequestTask.kt:44)
>   com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.RequestTask.call(RequestTask.kt:14)
>   com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt.response(Deserializable.kt:166)
>   com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.DefaultRequest.responseObject(DefaultRequest.kt:463)

while calling

```
url.httpGet().responseObject(moshiDeserializerOf(RestContextResult::class.java))
```

Do I need to use coroutines not to block a thread? Whats wring here?

Comment: it is probably an attempt to deserialize a null value into a non-nullable field (e.g. a Kotlin type without '?' and the end) It looks like the stack trace is partially included